# How to detect the previous buffer via '#' exist?

Tags: vimscript

As title. I'm trying to call `bd #` while it fails when the previous buffer doesn't exist. So my question is how to detect this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The previous buffer (any buffer) number can be obtained via

```
echo bufnr('#')
```

If the buffer is invalid, this will return -1, otherwise it is the number of the buffer.